# Autoclose alert doesn't alert

Tags: javascript, php

I cannot se why my autoclose doesn't work.
I use php to echo out javascript. I do echo both script. First the "not working" and then the "working". Only the "working" script shows up!
What's wrong?

**Not working**

```
echo "<div class='alert-message'></div>";
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
  echo "$('.alert-message').alert();";
  echo "window.setTimeout(function() { $('.alert-message').alert('close'); }, 5000);";
echo "</script>";
```

**Works**

```
//Echo succes
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
  echo "alert('Välkommen');";
  echo 'window.location = "page.php"';
echo "</script>";
die();
```

Comment: It's not supposed even to open. Does alert open?

Comment: No, nothing happends. In my code i run both scripts. The "Not working" first and the working script just after. The working script alerts

Comment: Where does the jQuery `.alert()` method come from? A plugin? Which one? What is the console saying?

Comment: @Boldewyn I use Jquery and bootstrap. So i guess the .alert is from that? otherwise, thats whats missing!

Comment: Console says Undefined $.... hmm maby the jquery aint reaching the php file...

Comment: @Boldewyn: I load the bootstrap.js that contains the .alert in the html file that holds the button that loads the php file. Do i need to load bootstrap.js in the php file to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.alert-message` div is not yet loaded in DOM when you are using it. Try to echo it before script:

```
echo "<div class='alert-message'></div>";    
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
  echo "$('.alert-message').alert();";
  echo "window.setTimeout(function() { $('.alert-message').alert('close'); }, 5000);";
echo "</script>";
```

Comment: I see your point and will move it. But it's still not working!?

Comment: Make sure to load alert plugin. Scripts order should be jquery, jquery.alert, your script.

Comment: $dfsq : I load bootstrap.js that contains alert.js in the HTML. The alert is in a php file that triggers with a btn. Do i need to load bootstrap.js in the php file to?

Comment: HTML page should include jquery.js, then bootstrap.js and after them your script. Open console and check for errors F12, there are probably some.

Comment: My script isn't placed in the html because of diffrent POSTED actions.. i need the alert in the php file..

Comment: PHP generates HTML as the result to output to browser. There are errors in console. Check them F12 to see why it doesn't work for you.